# How to convert a list of lists into a CSV file format?

Tags: python, csv

How to convert a list of lists into a CSV file format in python?

This is what I have, a list of lists:

```
[
    ['Node', 'Resource', 'Actual Number', 'Maximum Number Allowed', 'Usage'],
    ['node1', 'AuC Data Management', '5586618', '5820000', '95%'],
    ['node2', 'Enhanced Multi-Level Precedence and Pre-Emption Service (eMLPP)', '1', '3001', '0%']
    ...
]
```

What I want csv:

```
Node,Resource,Actual Number,Maximum Number Allowed,Usage
node1,AuC Data Management,5586618,5820000,95%
node2,Enhanced Multi-Level Precedence and Pre-Emption Service (eMLPP),1,3001,0%
...
```

Apologies but its been a while since I looked at python and this is what I am working on so far:

```
>>> x
[['Node', 'Resource', 'Actual Number', 'Maximum Number Allowed', 'Usage'], ['node1', 'AuC Data Management', '5586618', '5820000', '95%'], ['node2', 'Enhanced Multi-Level Precedence and Pre-Emption Service (eMLPP)', '1', '3001', '0%']]

>>> x[0]
['Node', 'Resource', 'Actual Number', 'Maximum Number Allowed', 'Usage']
```

In addition, is there a library/resource out there with some code that can make this conversion for the various permutations that the list of lists could come in?

Possible related question:
[Python csv file writing a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588259/python-csv-file-writing-a-list-of-lists)
[Writing a Python list of lists to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file) 
[CSV IO python: converting a csv file into a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169527/csv-io-python-converting-a-csv-file-into-a-list-of-lists) 
[Write a list of lists into csv in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54416008/write-a-list-of-lists-into-csv-in-python)
[Convert this list of lists in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020311/convert-this-list-of-lists-in-csv)

Comment: Asking for libraries, tools, or off-site resources recommendation is off-topic in here. Also, StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module it's got your back.

```
import csv

with open('somefile.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as csv_out:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    rows = [
        ['Node', 'Resource', 'Actual Number', 'Maximum Number Allowed', 'Usage'],
        ['node1', 'AuC Data Management', '5586618', '5820000', '95%'],
        ['node2', 'Enhanced Multi-Level Precedence and Pre-Emption Service (eMLPP)', '1', '3001', '0%']
]
    writer.writerows(rows)
```